# Python, how to use __setattr__ on dictionary object that is part of the class that overloads the method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setattr

As illustrated in the code below, why can't I use `__setattr__` to set values on a dict that is part of the class that overloads the method? I expected that `b.hello` would not exist.

```
class MyClass():

    datastore = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.datastore = {}

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.datastore[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.datastore[key] = value

a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()

a.hello = "err"

print a.hello # err
print b.hello # err
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b.hello` prints your string "err" because `datastore` is an attribute of the class itself, not of objects of the class. Therefore, when you initialize it in `a`, `b` can also access it.

Therefore, remove the `datastore = {}` from the class.

Furthermore, from the Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__):

> if `__setattr__()` wants to assign to an instance attribute, it should
>   not simply execute `self.name = value` — this would cause a recursive
>   call to itself. Instead, it should insert the value in the dictionary
>   of instance attributes, e.g., `self.__dict__[name] = value`. For
>   new-style classes, rather than accessing the instance dictionary, it
>   should call the base class method with the same name, for example,
>   `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`.

So, change your code to:

```
class MyClass(object): # Use new style classes
    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'datastore', {}) # This prevents infinite recursion when setting attributes

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.datastore[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.datastore[key] = value

a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()

a.hello = "err"

print a.hello # Works
print b.hello # Gives an error
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me first explain why this occurs:

```
class MyClass():

    datastore = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.datastore = {} # calls __setattr__
```

As you can see, your first variable definition in `__init__` ends up calling `__setattr__`

```
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.datastore[key] = value
```

The instance does not yet have the `datastore` attribute because it is still in the process of being defined. So this line `self.datastore[key] = value` first trys to look up `datastore` in the instance's `__dict__` but can't find it! Then it looks up one level in the class tree, where it does find it, as a class attribute!

Remember this:

```
class MyClass():

    datastore = {}
```

This is pretty confusing to begin with, since you have both an instance variable and a class variable with the same name, you should **not** have both.

So you can change your `__init__` to this:

```
object.__setattr__(self, 'datastore', {})
```

Like @Dhara suggested, or you can use the more general approach which I would recommend:

```
super(MyClass, self).__setattr__('datastore', {})
```

Where the latter option only works for new-style classes (which are better in every way!) which you should be using!
Just add `object` as a superclass

```
class MyClass(object): # In Py3k you don't need to since all classes are newstyle
```

One thing to note:

```
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.datastore[key] = value
```

Only works because you are setting the key of a dictionary and not an attribute of the instance. Be careful not to do things like

```
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.datastore = {} # for example
```

because that will result in infinite recursion, if you ever want to do something similar in `__setattr__` use the same trick from before:

```
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(MyClass, self).__setattr__('datastore', {})
```

The final result should look like:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__setattr__('datastore', {})

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.datastore[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.datastore[key] = value


a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()
a.hello = "err"
print a.hello
print b.hello
```

Comment: Thank you for your perfect explanation. Can you explain this code you have wrote more:
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(MyClass, self).__setattr__('datastore', {})
I mean why you use super.setattr...?

Comment: @Shahryar Since `__setattrr__` is using `self.datastore` which doesn't exist yet

Comment: so it will call the __setattr__ of the super class? why we need this? i understand all the codes here and in every other answers. The only thing i don't get is this call to super. Why would we need this?

Comment: If you want to find out why., simply remove the `super(MyClass, self).__setattr__('datastore', {})` and change it to `self.datastore = {}` and try run `a = MyClass()` and see what happens

Comment: why can't we simply say self[name] = value? is it wrong? @jamylak